# Math Equation to text

Tags: vb.net, math, equation

Is there a way to convert Math Equations to a Text?

ex.

```
 3π * 3 = x
```

out put will be

```
3(3.141592) multiplied by 3 equals to x
```

Comment: I think only way you can achieve this is by storing text reference to each special character somewhere in database or arraylist ... and use that to translate your Equations . eg: π = 3.141592 in arraylist

Comment: This seems like it could be done in VB.NET but it would be a bit more complex than in another language (ironically). I suggest you convert the entire equation to a string and store it character by character into an array, and then create a loop which scans each value of the array and if it is a math symbol it changes it to a word with the equivalent meaning. Then extract each character from teh array and turn it back into a string. Just throwing ideas...

Comment: yes maybe that's the only way.. so there no such codes or auto conversion ?

Answer (score 1):

By default Its not possible, You can write a code in such way that it will get the correct string(word) for different symbols and numbers. You can use the database for storing the words or you can do it with your functions.